# Change default Enum mapping strategy on MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I see that the generated code uses `name()` method to convert an `enum` to a `String`, but I would like to use `toString()` method insteed. Is it possible to configure it "globally"?

Answer (score 0):

For MapStruct 1.3Beta1, just define:

```
default String map(Enum<SourceEnum> e) {
    return e.toString();
}
```

in your @Mapper annotated interface or in your used mapper.

Comment: No.. Its 1.3Beta1.. SourceEnum could be any enum you like.

Comment: I need all my enums to use toString(), not  just some.

Comment: Remove the generic argument?